# The file "bitcoin.conf" does not exist. Where can I find this file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf, ordinals

I'm trying to do it by applying Casey Rodarmor's "HOW TO ORDINAL INSCRIPTION" videos. I did not install BitcoinCore directly. But even though I did exactly the instructions in the video, I got stuck at the "bitcoin.conf" stage. I couldn't find this file at all. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, you need to **create/generate** the ``bitcoin.conf`` file in your bitcoin directory.